# Reweight observations after subsetting

Tags: r, subset, survey, subsampling

I have a dataset containing a weight column, which I would like to subset while adjusting these weights to keep it representative of the original dataset. 
Let us say I have the dataframe :

```
data.frame(Age=c(10,20,30,25,50,60,40),
           Country=c("Germany","Germany","Germany","China","China","China","China"),
           Class=c("A", "B", NA, NA, "B", "A", "A"),
           Weight=c(1.1, 0.8, 1.2, 1.7, 0.7, 1.3, 0.9))
```

I would like to remove `NA` rows in the column `Class`, and update the `Weight` column to keep my sample representative of the original dataset given the columns `Age` and `Country`. (The above dataframe may be too small for such question, but this is just for illustration).

Answer (score 0):

```
df.fillna(df.mean())
```

if want to fill Na values with mean or other specific value you can simply run this code.

```
data.fillna()
```

is use for fill nan values in pandas dataframe you can put value whatever you want to replace

Comment: I know how to treat NA. In fact I rather want to resample a posteriori.